# Eclipse Git no warnings

Tags: eclipse, git, warnings

I added a java project to a git repository via the pre- installed git plugin in Eclipse. Now Eclipse does't show me warnings anymore (if I make a typo for example).
If I create a new non-git project, it shows warnings just fine.
I looked in the preferences, but nothing seems to be wrong there. Any ideas on how to fix this?